# Not able to downcast a List<num> to a List<int>

Tags: dart

```
void main() {
  var foo = number as int; // Works
  for (var bar in numbers as List<int>) {} // Run-time error
}

num get number => 0;

List<num> get numbers => [0];
```

Note: I'm not looking for a solution how to make that work. The question is why I'm unable to downcast a `List<num>` to a `List<int>` when the list is actually a type of `List<int>`.

Comment: [Why are generics covariant](https://dart.dev/faq#q-why-are-generics-covariant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your list *is not* a `List<int>`.

The list value is generated by

```dart
List<num> get numbers => [0];
```

You didn't write a type on the list literal, like `<int>[0]`, so the type of the list will be inferred for you.
Dart uses two pieces of information to infer that type:

- The context type (what is needed by the context) of `List<num>`. Not all expressions have a context type, but this one does.
- The element types (what's required by the elements) which is `int`.

If there is a context type, it always wins. So, your getter is inferred to be:

```dart
List<num> get numbers => <num>[0];
```

When you then try to do `numbers as List<int>`, it fails because a `List<num>` is-not a `List<int>` (the subtyping is the other way around).

For other people actually looking for a solution, you can either convert the list to a `List<int>`, by making a new list or by wrapping it using `cast`, or you can cast the individual elements. Or you can force an implicit down-cast. In all the cases, the code *will* fail if the list ends up containing a non-`int` value.

```dart
for (var bar in <int>[...numbers as List<dynamic>]) { ... }
for (var bar in numbers.cast<int>()) { ... }
for (int bar in numbers as List<dynamic>) { ... }
for (var bar in numbers) { ... bar as int ... }
```

Comment: Wow what a great explanation was that! Sir in your 3rd solution when we are doing `numbers as List<dynamic>`, is this part considered an upcast or downcast? The entire expression is a downcast that I know.

Comment: The cast of `numbers` to `List<dynamic>` is an up-cast. When iterating, every element will be down-cast to `int` from `dynamic`. It's potentially dangerous because it wouldn't catch `numbers` being a `List<String>` instead. I could currently have just done `for (int bar in numbers) ...`, which would implicitly downcast each element from `num` to `int`, but that will stop working when the Null Safety feature is released and all implicit downcasts stop working ... except those from `dynamic`.

Comment: Got it, thanks. But tell me one thing, where can I find this much of information about Dart? Docs doesn't cover what you know. Is asking question on SO and waiting for your response is the only way?

Comment: This answer combines language features (`<int>[...]`), library features (`.cast`) and type system behavior (implicit downcasts). Each of the are documented individually, either in the platform library documentation, the language feature release post (or the specification), or in the Dart 2.0 type system explanation. Dart doesn't have a single monolithic language+libraries+common packages introduction text. Maybe it should, but that's quite an undertaking.

Comment: I see unnecessary cast warning in this line `numbers as List<dynamic>`, although you can't remove it also. Should I create an issue for this?